# 8086 user defined interrupts

Tags: assembly, interrupt, x86-16

I use masm assembler for 8086 programs. I want to implement user defined interrupts but could not find a way to do it. I only know how to implement dos interrupts(INT 21H) and bios interrupts (INT 10H).
I have studied that 8086 has space for user defined interrupts(from 32 to 255 in the interrupt vector table)

How do I make use of these interrupts in masm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 8086 processor (and subsequent Intel processors running in real mode) uses an interrupt pointer table to figure out what to do when an interrupt is thrown. This table resides in the first 1k of low memory (`0000:0000 - 0000:03ff`) and contains a table of `CS:IP` values - one for each of 256 possible interrupts - to load when an interrupt occurs.

When your program starts, it needs to populate the entries in this table corresponding to the interrupts it wants to use, with the corresponding function pointers in (I think) little-endian encoding. Take care not to clash with any other interrupts already defined. After you've done this, and if interrupts are enabled, your interrupt handler should be called automatically whenever the corresponding interrupt is thrown. Remember to `IRET` at the end of your interrupt handlers, to restore the state of `CS:IP` and `FLAGS`, which are pushed to the stack as soon as an interrupt is triggered.

(I don't know if you can remap e.g. `INT 21h` to do something else, having not tried this myself, but I don't imagine the results of doing this by accident would be pretty.)

Comment: when we debug the program the cs takes any random value which we cannot control.So how do I know where to write my interrupt routine?For example I want to generate an interrupt every time the carry flag is set. how do I do that?

Comment: @Ross If you're talking about populating the interrupt pointer table, then it doesn't matter what the current `CS` value is since `MOV` uses `DS` by default. If you're talking about what `CS:IP` to write in the table itself, your assembler should be able to give you function pointers (and the `CS` value in the table overrides what was there when the interrupt fires, see 8086 manual). Interrupt on flag change doesn't appear to be something that can be done directly; you could maybe write a single-step handler that checks for this and throws your interrupt of choice, but this is *slow*.

Comment: The best method how to hook DOS with a new interrupt routine is the service http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2602.htm , see an example https://euroassembler.eu/prodos16/tsrclock.htm